# Underfull \hbox (badness ...) in paragraph at lines x-y

Tags: titlesec, tcolorbox, warnings

I get the following error:

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 5217) in paragraph at lines 57--57
```

I know it is a very common warning but I don't know how to fix it, this time it happens when a section name needs more than one line to span, I'm using `tcolorbox` and `titlesec` to format the sections.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,x11names,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[UTF8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish,mexico]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}
    {\normalfont\Large\sffamily\bfseries\color{CadetBlue4}}
    {\tcbox[colback=CadetBlue4, colframe=CadetBlue4, coltext=CadetBlue2!20, on line, boxsep=0pt, left=4pt, right=4pt, top=4pt, bottom=4pt]{\thesection}}{0.2em}{}


\newcommand\numberthis{\addtocounter{equation}{1}\tag{\theequation}}
\renewcommand{\d}{\mathrm{d}}
\author{Lara Serrano Paul Alfonso\\Ingeniería Mecánica}
\title{\tcbox[colback=CadetBlue4, colframe=CadetBlue4, coltext=CadetBlue2!20, on line, boxsep=0pt, left=4pt, right=4pt, top=4pt, bottom=4pt]{{\huge \textbf{Momentos de Área}}}}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Segundo momento de área}
Se considera, de nuevo, un área $A$ en el plano $xy$, el segundo momento de área, o también conocido como \emph{momento rectangular de inercia}, se define como
\begin{align*}
I_x=\int_A\!y^2\,\d A&&I_y=\int_A\!x^2\,\d A\numberthis\label{eq:6}
\end{align*}      
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could add `\raggedright` to section format and long section titles won't show this warning. Section titles will be flushed left and not adjusted to right margin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your section title uses a large font on a narrow line, so there is no good place to insert a line break, while keeping the first line right justified. This is discussed in chapter 6 of the TeXbook. One way to get a better result is to put in a manual line break:

```
\section{Segundo momento de \\ área}
```